# React JS - How to increment a number from 1 to 9 minutes per minute?

Tags: reactjs, increment

How to increment a number from 1 to 9 minutes per minute?
I need to increment a number from one to nine every minute. After going through the nine numbers, go back to the beginning.

I need to  change a className per minute. I try this:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(1);

useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => incrementCount, 3000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timer);
  }, []);

  
  const incrementCount = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  const name =  `C${count}`;
```

Now the className is C1, but after a minute I need C2...

Comment: What did you already try? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @DerMolly I need to  change a className per minute. I try this: 
    const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        const timer = setTimeout(() => incrementCount, 3000);
        return () => clearTimeout(timer);
      }, []);
    
      
      const incrementCount = () => {
        setCount(count + 1);
      };

      const name =  `C${count}`;

<div className = {name}>

Now the className is C1, but after a minute I need C2...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided basically works. It just needed some tweaks:

1. you forgot to add brackets to `incrementCount` in `setTimeout`
2. you need to but the handler in the `useEffect` or maybe in a `useCallback`, because the way you did it the renderer would recreate the callback on each render
3. you need to add `count` to the dependencies of `useEffect`, but this is only the case if you move the callback `incrementCount` into the `useEffect`

[here is a working example code](https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-voice-9puucg?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thank u! it's work! And how to limit the counter to 9?

Comment: You can get the currentState of `count` in `incrementCounter` like this
`const incrementCount = () => { setCount((oldCount) => oldCount + 1); };`. From there you can make the function like you want.